# Inaccurate slider intervals and slider position Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've been recently dealing with a weird behavior of sliderInput.

The problem is following:
sliderInput is created **ui.R** this way

```
sliderInput("firstSlider", "Item Slider", min=1, value=1, max=10,
                                             step = 1, animate=TRUE)
```

After the first run of the App I use the updateSliderInput in **server.R** this way

```
observe({
    updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "firstSlider", max=20)
})
```

Slider is updated to the max value set to 20, but the ticks or scaling behaves in a rather weird way

[Scaling of sliderInput after updateSliderInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQQ6b.jpg)

Note that it seems there are two values between 1 and 3 or 3 and 5, etc., but there is obviously only one value. 
Interestingly, it seems there are two values between 9 and 12 and there really are two values, but then again, between 12 and 14 is just one value, although it seems like there should be two values.

Also note that the 
[slider positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBN62.jpg)
is not accurate.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? I would be very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Hey, I encoutered the same problem, but with my slider using dates. Did you fix it?